# how to modify one xml input using variable from second xml input in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

My question is how to change values in <color> in sample1.xml based on the same <id> in sample2.xml

#### sample1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <color>red</color>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <color>blue</color>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>3</id>
        <color>green></color>
    </item>
</root>
```

#### sample 2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <item>
      <id>1</id>
      <color>yellow</color>
   </item>
   <item>
      <id>3</id>
      <color>white</color>
   </item>
</root>
```

#### expected output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <color>yellow</color>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <color>blue</color>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>3</id>
        <color>white></color>
    </item>
</root>
```

I only know how to copy entire sample1.xml to output, but I don't know how to remember ids from sample2.xml, and by that values make changes to sample1.
Don't know if is possible, but probably I must use variables on some unknown way.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" extension-element-prefixes="saxon"
version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" media-type="text/xml" />
   
    <xsl:param name="sample1"/>
    <xsl:param name="sample1_xml" select="saxon:parse($sample1)"/>

    <xsl:param name="sample2"/>
    <xsl:param name="sample2_xml" select="saxon:parse($sample2)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="initial">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$sample1_xml/node()"/> <!-- this is only for copying entire sample1 file -->

    </xsl:template>

    <!-- copy all nodes and values -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I really don't have idea what is the right way to do that, because I am new to XSLT 2.0. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was beaten to this by Martin Honnen, but here's my solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            exclude-result-prefixes="xs" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" extension-element-prefixes="saxon"
            version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" media-type="text/xml"/>

<xsl:param name="sample1"/>
<xsl:param name="sample1_xml" select="saxon:parse($sample1)"/>

<xsl:param name="sample2"/>
<xsl:param name="sample2_xml" select="saxon:parse($sample2)"/>

<xsl:template match="/" name="initial">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$sample1_xml/node()"/>
    <!-- this is only for copying entire sample1 file -->

</xsl:template>

<!-- copy all nodes and values -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root/item/color">
    <xsl:param name="id" select="parent::item/id/text()"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$sample2_xml/root/item[id=$id]/color">
                <xsl:value-of select="$sample2_xml/root/item[id=$id]/color/text()"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a key `<xsl:key name="id" match="item" use="id"/>` and then add a template

```
<xsl:template match="item[key('id', id, $sample2_xml)]/color">
  <xsl:copy-of select="key('id', ../id, $sample2_xml)/color"/>
</xsl:template>
```

So the complete sample is

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs saxon"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" media-type="text/xml" />

    <xsl:param name="sample1" as="xs:string"><![CDATA[<root>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <color>red</color>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <color>blue</color>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>3</id>
        <color>green></color>
    </item>
</root>]]></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="sample1_xml" select="saxon:parse($sample1)"/>

    <xsl:param name="sample2" as="xs:string"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <item>
      <id>1</id>
      <color>yellow</color>
   </item>
   <item>
      <id>3</id>
      <color>white</color>
   </item>
</root>]]></xsl:param>


    <xsl:param name="sample2_xml" select="saxon:parse($sample2)"/>

    <xsl:key name="id" match="item" use="id"/>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="initial">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$sample1_xml/node()"/> <!-- this is only for copying entire sample1 file -->

    </xsl:template>

    <!-- copy all nodes and values -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item[key('id', id, $sample2_xml)]/color">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('id', ../id, $sample2_xml)/color"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you very much for speedy answer! Could you describe me how to define key and how to match it inside the template if tags don't have the same name? I am confused about how to define key and match it.

I cannot get good result if  I rename '<id>' in sample2 to '<new>', and '<color>' in sample2 to 'new_color'. Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, I did already provide an example for the key, obviously if you change the format of the second file then you need to adapt the key to `<xsl:key name="id" match="item" use="new"/>` and the template to `<xsl:template match="item[key('id', id, $sample2_xml)]/color"><xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="key('id', ../id, $sample2_xml)/new_color"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`.